# Is this laptop suitable for Ethereum mining?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum

I have a laptop with 4 GB of RAM, 1 TB HDD and an i3 processor running Windows 10 and Intel HD Graphics 520. Is there any chance I can mine Ethereum or Litecoin using this setup? If yes please someone tell me how to get started or post a link.

Comment: Check the answers to this question in another thread: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/34228/28780

Answer (score 1):

Nothing forbids you to mine Ethereum, however mining such as mining bitcoin,litecoin or Ethereum is most of the time not profitable unless you have a very low cost of power.

Below you'll find some links, however i recommend you if you want to mine -
 ether, litecoin or most known cryptocurrencies - to mine on a pool instead of mining on your own where you'll have no chance to mine a whole block on your own unless having a mining farm or being the luckiest person in the world as both btc, ltc and eth are mined with PoW.

Mining on a pool makes allows you to join a pool of miners where the reward is distributed beetween all those that contributed in mining a bloc minus a small fee for the mining pool.

[How to mine ethereum on windows 10](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/)

[Mine ether on minergate](https://en.minergate.com/faq/how-to-mine-eth-with-console)

[How to mine litecoin](https://www.coindesk.com/information/how-to-mine-litecoin/)

[Mining Litecoin on Minergate](https://minergate.com/blog/bitcoin-litecoin-mining/)