# Can I mine Ethereum from AMD Laptop?

Tags: mining

I have below configuration laptop

> windows 7 64 bits
>
> AMD A4-3305M APU with Radeon HD Graphics,
>
> 4 GB RAM
>
> AMD RADEON HD 6480G

"" CAN I MINE ETHEREUM ON MY LAPTOP ""

Thanks in advance.. Please guide..

Comment: Related: https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can mine Ethereum on every computer with 4 GB RAM. The real question is whether it will be profitable.

The answer is no. Your graphics processor does not have its own memory, and it's just not fast enough. You will also decrease the lifetime of your laptop by running it at full power for a long time. Depending on your electricity price, you would probably spend more money on electricity than you get back in mined ether.

Comment: ya. I agree with your suggestion. Thanks for the quick reply. Any small investment plan for mining if you got?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a calculator for ETH mining. What's most interesting about the calculator results is the footnote at the very bottom, which tells you the average days to find one block for a given hash rate.

https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

My gaming rig is a Core i7, 16GB RAM, R9 280X GPU, and an SSD. Now that it's sync'd I see I'm getting about 12 MH/s. The calculator tells me I could earn around $40/month with this rig, which sounds OK. BUT, the calculator also tells me it will take an average of 2,684 days for me to win a block! In other words it could take YEARS (and luck) before I get anything at all with the system grinding 24/7. I myself don't see Ethereum, and most other crypto currencies, as good long term investments. So I conclude that a rig like mine is a waste of time for solo mining. There's some serious competition out there cranking 1000's of MH/s who will win most of the blocks.

Using that same calculator I plotted some points to see the curve of average days to find a block vs MH/s - it's a non-linear curve. From that curve I conclude that if you're not running at least 120 MH/s then it's going to be too long-term an investment. I suppose a pool might be the answer if you don't want to build a big rig, but a laptop is pretty much out of the question even for a pool.

Here's the plot:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnKlcLS78uKliA5fm2nn5roXFjJc

Answer (score 1):

Mining Ethereum these days is becoming more and more complex. Eth 2.0 is causing even more confusion to make matters worse. However, questions about [mining ethereum from your laptop](https://cryptominertips.com/can-i-mine-ethereum-on-my-laptop/) have come up quite often, so I do my best to answer.

In short, the answer is no; however, for some gaming laptops with a 6GB GPU or higher, you can technically mine Ethereum with them, so if your laptop is not a gaming laptop equipped with a 6GB GPU, sorry, the answers a hard NO.

At some point, I'm sure when Eth was first released, this was possible, but these days, the DAG file and mining difficulty make it impossible to do with a CPU. Why you might ask, and in short, my answer to this is that's the way these blockchains are designed to evolve.

However, I want to back and state that even with having a laptop with a 6GB or better GPU, you should still proceed to mine Eth with caution. The reason is that laptops are well equipped to deal with the constant heat that mining emits due to the machine running heavy math calculations 24/7.

You can add ons items such as extra fans or install software that allows you to adjust the CPU fan speeds. Whatever you do, make sure the laptop is running in a room that is cool with lots of circulating fresh air.

If you really want to mine Ethreum, you should really look into building a GPU mining rig with several GPUs instead of trying to run one GPU through a laptop. I'm not saying you can't mine some form of a coin with a laptop and come out on top, but for Eth, you need alot of decent hardware to have a sizeable yield these days.

I hope my answer helps someone out...

*Disclaimer*: This answer contains links to Crypto Miner Tips with which I am affiliated with. Crypto Miner Tips is a free resource all about mining cryptocurrecny.

Comment: It's okay to link to websites you're affiliated with, however, you **must** disclose your affiliation with them in your answer. See our [promotion policy](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and thanks for being so cool about it. I plan to provide value to the community as much as possible. Please review my new disclaimer I added to my response and see if that is sufficient.

Comment: Looks good! Thank you for disclosing your affiliation! Keep in mind, you're very welcome to continue contributing in this manner, however it's greatly encouraged that you only link to your own website/resources if it's supplementary and not overly promotional.